# Given a text file containing cmd commands, how can I use a batch file to loop and run them?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using a text file to store a list of cmd commands. I am using the commands to gather information about users on my domain. There are about 400 lines of text each following the format of `net user someuser > someuser.txt` I want to use a batch file to loop through the single text file line by line and execute the commands.

Comment: Name your text file `something.bat` and double click it. Use `>>` which appends to the file.

Comment: Why do you want that? A batch file is nothing but a text file containing `cmd` commands... Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I don't have much experience with batch files, but your approach could work. I have other things to implement within the batch file so that's why I wanted to keep it to one batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This [FOR loop](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) should do the trick:

```
 FOR /F %%c IN ('type commands.txt') DO %%c
```

Comment: Useless use of `type` and arguments within commands.txt will be dropped.  Do `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%c in ("commands.txt")...` instead.

Comment: @rojo Wasn't aware of those. Thank you!